# Netbeans generate getter and setter

Tags: java, netbeans, setter, getter, netbeans-7.4

I've got some trouble with the Netbeans IDE. Please help me. When I'm coding in Java, when I want to generate getters and setters automatically, Netbeans generates these methods with Turkish characters (replaces the english `i` with 'ı'), e.g. `voıd` or `ınt` and `publıc`. How can I fix that problem? Here is part of my trouble:

```
public ınt getAge() {
    return age
}

publıc voıd setAge(ınt age) {
    this.age = age;
}
```

My Netbeans version is 7.4.

Comment: What font are you using?  Have you considered changing the local for the JVM?

Comment: I'm using default Netbeans font and I dont change my font